# блокирование SIGPIPE, какие есть особенности/ограничения?

Tags: libevent

Задача простая: демон-сервис с http-cервером с тредами на базе libevent,
надо заблокировать SIGPIPE

в тестовом приложении прекрасно работает конструкция

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

которая успешно решает задачу, однако в основном приложении нет - игнорирование не работает.
гугление дало невнятную и противоречивую информацию, мол с тредами вышеприведенная конструкция не работает, надо другую. в других местах пишут, что блокировка отработает 1 раз и затем ее надо поставить снова.
безусловно все варианты были перепробованы и никакой из них в основном приложении результата не дал.

при этом в тестовом демоне-сервере с тредами все работает идеально и блокировка обозначенная даже в родителе процесса с http-серверами-тредами
работает идеально. времени на методом тыка перебрать мегабайты кода в основном приложении увы нет.

отсюда вопрос какие есть особенности/ограничения ? что может "выключить" вышеобозначенную конструкцию ?

PS: Centos 6 x86-64

Answer (score 0):

Выявлено, что блокировкой занимается библиотека OCILIB.